# App Store Connect does not show all sales - why?

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit, in-app-subscription, app-store-connect

In order to be able to better estimate the revenue income of our app, we implemented a Database function that reliably (we tested it in Sandbox mode) increases a subscription counter for the subscription that was made by one once a subscription has been made.
This function is only triggered once an in-app purchase has been successful (i.e. when we receive the feedback from StoreKit to enable the Premium functions). Now, we have found **enormous discrepancies** between the data we observed and the data App Store Connect gives us.

For the past two days, upon confirmation of purchase via StoreKit, our app has 13 times enabled premium functions on a monthly subscription basis, and 14 times on a yearly subscription basis.
However, App Store Connect tells us we had one yearly subscription and 5 monthlies.
Furthermore, for the one premium subscription that generated sales of $5.60, Apple has added proceeds of $3.73 - but that's more than 30% commission. That's almost 35%.

The sales that Apple has not accounted for amount to **more than $70.**

Can anybody explain to me what's going on, why Apple is not showing us subscriptions that definitely happened and takes more commission than agreed?

Comment: App Store Connect is the source of truth so I would examine how your analytics are tracking those events. Maybe you're counting trials as purchases?

Comment: You mentioned in a comment below that your data and Firebases is identical. Do you have free trials on your subscriptions? Firebase incorrectly counts free trials as revenue in my app.

Answer (score 1):

My bet is that you are not aggregating the prices correctly on your database side. It is extremely complicated thing to do, despite superficially seeming simple.

The second guess is that ItunesConnect revenue is delayed by day or three (they were experiencing delays).

If you want to see know the revenue calculation is done correctly, I recommend hooking yourself to RevenueCat (quite simple process), and to double check numbers.

Comment: It's true that it is not too simple to do that. However, as mentioned, the app is only adding a new subscription upon receipt confirmation from StoreKit and after unlocking premium functions. Also, Firebase's and my data are identical. Really weird... thanks for your answers, though. RevenueCat seems like a great tool!

Comment: ITunesConnect can also experience severe delays ranging from day to three days to more.. It is also possible you are accounting sandbox transactions, it is also possible you are accounting transactions that have been refunded (or downgraded/upgraded), or transactions that are fake

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the price, don’t forget their is also sales tax/VAT that is deducted too. Eg. Any sales made in the UK will have 20% vat removed, then Apple takes 30% and you get the rest.